# HttpInterceptor implementation in C# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net

In Angular there is HttpInterceptor which make it really nice to intercept HttpClient call on the app, also handle errors of the request.

Is there a C#/.NET library that do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-3.1)

You have to override `SendAsync`

```
internal class MyHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         // Do before call

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // do after call

        return response;
    }
}

var handler = new MyHttpClientHandler();

var client = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("my-api-uri")
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for what is called Middelware in the ASP.net world. These are code that are placed in an http pipeline that can handle incoming requests and outgoing responses.
Have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that explains how it works and what you can do.

Comment: No, he means that he wants to intercept each http request he makes inside the his apllication using HttpClient, not the incoming requests from outside client who uses his application